# ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4' from .Elf file

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

i make test.py using pyqt, run python test.py, it run properly but after i make .Elf file it shows error Import-error: No module named 'PyQt4'

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               

        qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
        qbtn.move(50, 50)       

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Quit button')    
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

i want to make elf file of this test.py

Comment: have you installed Pyqt4?

Comment: yes i already installed it

Comment: maybe it is in a map with an other name?

Comment: when i write on terminal "python test.py " it run but when i make .elf file using pyinstaller test.py and goes to dist folder and run it it gives error No module named 'PyQt4'

Comment: if you go to the map with all the python site packages and look if the map maybe has the map an other name